# Counting balls in face centred cubic close packing

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, 3d, integer-lattices

Possibly too easy for stack exchange, but...

Consider a cubic close packing, or face centred cubic, arrangement of balls or radius $1$ in dimension $3$.

Suppose that the origin is the centre of one of the balls. Let $r$ be the distance to the origin.

I wish to count how many balls are located at a given distance.

That is easy to do in dimension $2$. The densest close packing arrangement is an hexagonal lattice, therefore we can count balls placed on dilated hexagons:
6 when $r=2$ and in general $6n$ when $r=2n$.

I would like a similar estimate in dimension 3. At $r=2$, there are exactly $12$ balls. At $r=2n$, how many balls? $12n^2$?

Comment: What is $r$? Are you asking about how many unit-size balls of the arrangement there are inside a ball of radius $r$? Can that larger ball be centered arbitrarily? What about balls which are partially contained in the larger ball, do they count or not? Please be more specific.

Comment: @MvG I have now clarified the question, I hope

Comment: @username: What you are describing is the coordination number sequence of a lattice or packing. This is related to but different from the theta series or function of a lattice or packing.